# Running a toggle command faster when something is visible?

Tags: jquery, toggle

My aim is to run something faster once the user can see it. To explain, once the user clicks the menu button it will open, which is fine but when the user clicks to close the menu, it should close the menu down faster. However my code does not want to fire the second 'else if' part of my code.

Here my code :

```
  $(document).ready( function() {                       
   if ( !$(".TopList1").is(":visible")  ) { 
    $('.MenuButton').click(function() {         
        $( ".TopList1" ).toggle("slide", {direction: "down"}, 1000);
        $( ".TopList2" ).delay(800).toggle("slide", {direction: "down"}, 800);
        $( ".LeftList1" ).toggle("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);
        $( ".LeftList2" ).delay(800).toggle("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);
    });
   } else if ( $(".TopList1").is(":visible")  )  {
    $('.MenuButton').click(function() {         
        $( ".TopList1" ).toggle("slide", {direction: "down"}, 800);
        $( ".TopList2" ).toggle("slide", {direction: "down"}, 800);
        $( ".LeftList1" ).toggle("slide", {direction: "left"}, 800);
        $( ".LeftList2" ).toggle("slide", {direction: "left"}, 800);
    });
   }
});
```

Update:

Heres the [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/XkjXA/), the css is not right on there but you can get the idea, the links open up but i want them to close at all the same time! - The end result might not even toggle the close but just fade out!

Comment: Can you share your html so we can fiddle it more easily?

Comment: or just make fiddle for us on jsfiddle

Comment: I think the if condition should go inside click()
 $('.MenuButton').click(function() { if(visible){do something} else {do something else})

Comment: I would add classes to open/closed elements. `:visible` in jQuery will often return true, it's not visible as you visually see. `Opacity: 0` would return true for `:visible`

Comment: You are doing the binding inside the if, it should be the other way round, the if should be inside the handler

Comment: see corrected fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XkjXA/1/

Comment: refactored version http://jsfiddle.net/XkjXA/3/

Comment: Many thanks for the help David! I not really used JQuery much in detail apart from fade in and out! I see what i was doing wrong. I work on it and post back the final code here. I just want to add something that will stop the user from closing the menu down until its completely loaded! - Many Thanks. Glenn.

Comment: @GlennCurtis added the new function http://jsfiddle.net/XkjXA/4/

Comment: @DavidFregoli - Sorry, my skills on JQuery are still basic, i am not sure, to what benefit you get from the added function? - Thanks Glenn

Comment: @GlennCurtis "I just want to add something that will stop the user from closing the menu down until its completely loaded" that thing you said >D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that your `if` statement was only being checked on initial load. As it evaluates to `true`, only the top half of your code was being triggered. The reason it works at all is because `toggle` is smart, so the top half both expands and collapses the submenus.

This code works:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var menuClosed = true;
    $('.MenuButton').click(function() {
        if (menuClosed) {
            menuClosed = false;
            $( ".TopList1" ).toggle("slide", {direction: "down"}, 1000);
            $( ".TopList2" ).delay(800).toggle("slide", {direction: "down"}, 800);
            $( ".LeftList1" ).toggle("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);
            $( ".LeftList2" ).delay(800).toggle("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);
        } else {
            menuClosed = true;
            $( ".TopList1" ).toggle(0);
            $( ".TopList2" ).toggle(0);
            $( ".LeftList1" ).toggle(0);
            $( ".LeftList2" ).toggle(0);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the options.

e.g.

```
$( "#effect" ).effect( selectedEffect, options, 500, callback );
```

http://jqueryui.com/effect/

Comment: btw, scratch what i said You are adding the event handler twice I see it now, but your code only runs once when the page is loaded, if there are changes after the page is loaded this code won't pick them up